# Find entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

We need to find an entire function $f$ that satisfies
$$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{2}{z-1}-\cos(z)+4$$
for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 1 \}$.

I suppose I'm just somewhat confused over how to get from $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ to something that can become $f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ is the logarithmic derivative of $f$. See it as what you get when you differentiate $\log(f(z))$. So, up to a constant
\begin{align}
\log(f(z))&=2\log(z-1)-\sin(z)+4z\\
&=\log\left((z-1)^2\right)-\sin(z)+4z.
\end{align}
Therefore, you can take
\begin{align}
f(z)&=\exp\left(\log\left((z-1)^2\right)-\sin(z)+4z\right)\\
&=(z-1)^2e^{4z-\sin(z)}.
\end{align}
This is not a rigorous argument, but it is easy to check that this entire function is actually a solution.